# Why dropdown menus does not work with all themes?

Tags: theming, routes, navigation

I am testing few drupal-6 themes for my blog and I observe that the drop-down menus in one theme does not show in another theme. I am specifically testing with [Blogbuzz](http://drupal.org/project/blogbuzz) and [Jackson](http://drupal.org/project/jackson). In my case, Blogbuzz shows the drop-down menus whereas Jackson does not. I have ticked the expanded options in the menues primary links in both cases, but I dont see the dropdown menus in Jackson. How can i make the jackson theme to show me the dropdown menus?

Answer (score 0):

The Jackson project page says:

> jQuery for Superfish and pngFix (optional):
>   In order to use the styles created for the Superfish drop-down menus and to fix the IE6 transparent png issue, you will need to download the following files and add them to the Jackson > scripts folder which you will need to create.
>
> Please note primary links can be created and are styled to work
>   without drop-down navigation.
>
> The following scripts are to be added only if you would like to use drop-down navigation on your website, or if you would like transparent images to display correctly for IE6.
>
> jQuery pngFix Plugin by Andreas Eberhard
>   jQuery Superfish Plugin by Joel Birch

By default, it is set not to use drop-downs.

Answer (score 0):

I tested several modules and finally opted by writing the menu in PHP, which reads directly from the Drupal system. You can check the following object and its properties:

```
$a = menu_tree_output( menu_tree_page_data("main-menu") );
foreach($a as $key => $value){ ... modify... write...each link ... }
```